# Ajax calls on keyup for differents inputs with timeouts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm having problems trying to fix this logic.

The page have more than one field and the idea is to save the inputs values in the database when the user stop writing.

This is the code:

```
var debounce = null;
        $overviewContainer.on('keyup change', 'input, textarea, select', function(){
            //<------------------Update Section Item ---------------->
            clearTimeout(debounce);
            console.log('aca se actualizando!');
            var savingMessage = '<div class="alert-container" style="width: 7%;"><div class="spinner spinner-alert" style="height: 60px; width: 60px;"></div>';
            $('#alerts').append(savingMessage);
            var $savingMessage = $(savingMessage).find('.spinner-alert');
            if($(this).attr('type') != 'file'){
                var $form = $(this).parents('form').first(),
                    $url = $form.attr('action');
                debounce = setTimeout(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: $url,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $form.serialize(),
                        maxConcurrency: 3,
                        success: function success(response) {
                            console.log($savingMessage);
                            $savingMessage.hide();
                            $('#alerts').innerAlert('success', response.message);
                        },
                        error: function error(response) {
                            $('#alerts').innerAlert('error', response.message);
                        }
                    });
                }, 1200);
            }
        });
```

I have two main problems with this:

1. The first one is that if the user leaves the page before the ajax finish, the value is not saved.
2. If the user update a field, and then, before the setimeout start, start to change another field, only the second one is saved, but the first one is ignored. I'm not sure how to approach this

For the first problem, I try to fix this by using the window.onbeforeunload if a spinner exists in order to prevent the user to leave if all is not saved, but Im not sure if is the best approach.

For the second one, my theory is that the timeout is beign overrided, so I was thinking on create a functon every time that a change is happening, or create unique ids for fields, and split the function for ID, but Im not sure at all about this.

Comment: 2) you should store your different timeouts so that you will still have access to them afterwards, instead of using and overwriting the same singular variable each time. You could for example store them in an object, using the ID of the current input field as property name.

Answer (score 0):

Add an beforeunload to see if the save has completed to warn the user that it is not saved.

```js
let isUnsaved = false;
let currentDebounce = null;

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
  if (isUnsaved) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return event.returnValue = '';
  }
});

$overviewContainer.on('keyup change', 'input, textarea, select', function() {
  //<------------------Update Section Item ---------------->
  clearTimeout(currentDebounce);
  isUnsaved = true;

  console.log('aca se actualizando!');
  var savingMessage = '<div class="alert-container" style="width: 7%;"><div class="spinner spinner-alert" style="height: 60px; width: 60px;"></div>';
  $('#alerts').append(savingMessage);
  var $savingMessage = $(savingMessage).find('.spinner-alert');

  if ($(this).attr('type') != 'file') {
    (function() {
      const $form = $(this).parents('form').first(),
      const $url = $form.attr('action');
        
      const instanceDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: $url,
          type: 'POST',
          data: $form.serialize(),
          maxConcurrency: 3,
          success: function success(response) {
            console.log($savingMessage);
            $savingMessage.hide();
            $('#alerts').innerAlert('success', response.message);
            
            // if the instance value is not matching the global, you know another save is queued up.
            isUnsaved = currentDebounce !== instanceDebounce;

          },
          error: function error(response) {
            $('#alerts').innerAlert('error', response.message);
            
            // if the instance value is not matching the global, you know another save is queued up.
            isUnsaved = currentDebounce !== instanceDebounce;
          }
        });
      }, 1200);
      
      // set the global to the instance value
      currentDebounce = instanceDebounce;
    }());
  }
});
```

Comment: mm, but this will work only if there is one field. If more than one field is changed, I will return a false 'unsaved' because maybe the second one is not finished yet.

Comment: There are ways around it.... store the last debounce into a variable and see if it matches the current one.

Comment: Made the change I commented about.